# Automatically detecting a file instead of using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

I have this code which picks up a file from: d2ve38282 and drops it locally into: D:\Test\MEP\TST\input\tEST.

1st attempt:

```
Move-Item "\\d2ve38282\AS2\Inbound\Test Orders\*.txt" -Destination "D:\Test\MEP\TST\input\tEST"
```

2nd attempt:

```
$FTBM = 'D:\Test Folder'
$FLTR = '*.*'

$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $FTBM, $FLTR -Property @{
    IncludeSubDirectories = $false;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Move-Item "D:\Test Folder\*.txt" -Destination "D:\Test Folder 2"

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
}
#Unregister-Event FileCreated
```

3rd attempt:

```
$FTBM = 'D:\Test Folder'
$FLTR = '*.*'

$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $FTBM, $FLTR -Property @{
    IncludeSubDirectories = $false;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Move-Item "D:\Test Folder\*.txt" -Destination "D:\Test Folder 2"
}"
#Unregister-Event FileCreated
```

How can I set this up to automatically run when it finds a Test Order in this folder: D:\Test Folder\?

Comment: Create a file system watcher on the remote host and have it push files to the destination.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, I will do some more investigation on this file system watcher and I will reply back with my results.

Comment: Hi, I have just included my 2nd attempt. This does not move the File as soon as it hits the folder, do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please stop wrapping code in arbitrary places to make it fit the content area width. Copy/paste your code *exactly* as it is in your script.

Comment: You run `Move-Item` before registering the watcher. How do you expect that to work? You need to move the file picked up by the watcher in the watcher action.

Comment: Hi, I have moved the move item, still no luck.

Comment: PLEASE. STOP. WRAPPING. CODE. IN. ARBITRARY. PLACES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$folder = 'c:\scripts\test' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                          
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

# Here, all three events are registerd.  You need only subscribe to events that you need:

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore red
Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}
```

Source: [FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

Dot Net version is always better than the WMI one. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, this simply says on the powershell screen that a file has been dropped into the folder I have had a look at this before hand. I need the folder to move once it hits the folder.

Comment: You can register that event too.

Comment: do you have an example of registering that event please?

Comment: @GLH:`$Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType`  will have all the variations. You can pick whichever you need.